# search function can not find user by name and surname

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

When I search for a user by Name and Surname, for example, John Doe, I can't find the user. Even there is a user by that name and surname in DB. However, when I search just for NAME or Surname I will find the user. How can I fix this?

```
public List<User> SearchByName(string search)
{
    return _dBcontext.Users.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search) || x.Surname.Contains(search)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When searching for "John Doe", your query is searching for records whose Name or Surname contain the entirety of "John Doe", e.g. `"John".Contains("John Doe")`. There are a few ways to resolve this, the two simplest that I can think of being:

1. Split apart your `search` input into `firstName` and `surname` variables, and compare the variables to their respective record variables,
2. use `search.Contains(x.Name) || search.Contains(x.Surname)`